# copy option values from one dropdown to another

Tags: c#

I have one dropdown named A with 4 option values. Another dropdown named B with 4 option values.

```
A: yellow, blue, green, orange
B: white, black, red, voilet
```

How can I add a mapping logic to copy option values from one dropdown to another dropdown in C#?

map and copy from yellow -> white, blue-> black, green-> red, orange -> voilet in dropdown B?

Comment: How is it decided which one to copy?

Comment: I only want to map with the above pairs without any condition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)? Refer to sample code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listA = new string[] { "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange" };
        var listB = new string[] { "white", "black", "red", "voilet" };

        // create the mapper
        Mapper.CreateMap<string, string>()
            .ConvertUsing(f => GetMappingValue(f));

       // then test listC
        var listC = new string[] { "yellow", "green", "orange", "blue" };
        var result = listC.Select(x => Mapper.Map<string>(x)).ToArray();

      // result should be 
      // "white", "red", "voilet", "black"
    }

    private static string GetMappingValue(string input)
    {
        if (input == "yellow")
            return "white";

        if (input == "blue")
            return "black";

        if (input == "green")
            return "red";

        if (input == "orange")
            return "voilet";

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```

Hope it helps.